# Installing many intances on the same PC - Inno Setup - Is it the right way?

Tags: inno-setup

My app can be installed many times on the same PC. The difference is the network path, from where installer was executed.
So, I generate the AppId dynamically using the hash of the path to the installer. In this way, if you're starting the installer from the same path, it gets the same appId and update will be done. If path is different, new instance will be installed.

I have a little problem also. The network path can be changed. Now user need to completely reinstall the app, otherwise after an update it gets a new AppId and it will be installed like a new app.

So I'm thinking about saving the first generated appId in a some file in the folder, from where installer will be executed and then get it from there.

The question is, if it is the right way to achieve all my needs.

Comment: Please explain what is this all about. Why are you installing the same application from different locations and treat them like different applications?

Comment: What do you mean by the "right" way? Have you tested it against each of your needs? And if so, has it met them/passed?

Comment: You may be better served asking this question on Software Engineering instead of Stack Overflow; it's a high-level design question and it's not asking for objective answers as currently phrased.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, we have a windows app. It is used to work with some data of some company. One app is able to work only with one company. Usually the application is located on a shared drive, so many users can work with it . To make it work faster I created an installer (inno setup), that copies large parts of the application to the local user. We have also different installations for each company on the shared drive. If the user works with many companies on the same PC, he can also use the installer to copy large parts from this installation.

Comment: @TylerH, yes, it's more design question, but it's also very specified with the used inno-installer and there is no special tag at software engineering

Answer (score 1):

Your users should not be changing the Installed directory (or network path as you say).  After installing a Windows application I would not expect to be able to change the folder names and/or path C:/ProgramFiles/MyApp to C:/ProFil/MyAppChangedName and expect that application to still function correctly.

Where does your AppId currently exist (the Registry?) since you say that it is not currently in the Application's installed directory?

Does your current 'setup' work with multiple installations or is that also broken since the AppId only existing once with multiple installations?

It is not very common to have an Installer and expect to be able to install multiple instances on one computer.  Normally the Registry changes and AppData directories would not play nice.  But some application don't seem to mind (Eclipse, etc).

You could put your application IDs in a file/folder in the AppData folder and have a list of all the application IDs in that file to use for you updates.  That way your AppIds are in a folder path (network path) that doesn't change.

Besides that it looks like you using a 3rd party application installation package 'Inno Setup'.  I am not familiar, but should it not show the users the options of 'Repair', 'Update', 'Re-Install', 'Uninstall' etc when running the Installer a second time.

I assume the issue is that when you run the Installer you expect it to know whether to update and install 'new' without user interaction.

Usually to update an application is done within the application.  Example: From within your application, File -> Update.

You could also add a Task Scheduler (Google adds one with Chrome) task to run the Update automatically every week etc.

I would expect an application to check for updates every time the user opens the application.  If an update is needed you could check the folder path at that point (since it should be wherever the exe is currently running) and if it is not found the user could point you to the desired Application instance network path (folder path) to update.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
The AppId is normally stored in the registry and inside uninstall log files and if you're starting this installer with the same AppId, update will be performed. AppId is saved immutable inside the "setup.exe", but it can also be calculated by starting this "setup.exe", so it is in my case.

Comment: I like your proposal to save an AppIDs in the AppData folder. I'll think about doing it. Thank you!